# Flowplayer validator Not Working in IE9 32-bit

Tags: internet-explorer-9, validation, flowplayer

Is there anything which I might need to add to make the Flowplayer Validator work in IE9 32-bit?

I am running both the Flowplayer validator demo and my website in IE9 from a development machine with Win7 64-bit OS; they work when I run them using IE 64-bit but not with a 32-bit version.

Already tried searching on Google but with no positive results. I really hope someone can help me out cause I've already lost too much time on this... Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone encounters my same issue, in my case it was being caused by an Internet Explorer plugin called DivX Plus Web Player HTML 5 Beta. Uninstalling this plugin solved the problem.